# Does $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ mean it is is defined at all points

Tags: functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be functions satisfying

$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) + f(x)f(y)$, $\hspace{5pt}$ and $\hspace{5pt}$   $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$

for all $x,y \in R $. $\hspace{5pt}$  Given $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} g(x)=1$

My question is when we state $g:R→R$, it means it is defined at all points but $g(x)$ cannot be defined at $x=0$. Also, $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} g(x)=1$ doesn't say $g(x)=1$.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem starts by saying $f$ and $g$ are each defined at all reals. [That is what the notations $f:R\to R, \  g:R \to R$ imply]. But then later in the problem by saying $g(x)=f(x)/x$ the problem contradicts itself, because of the issue at $x=0.$ The error is in the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ means that the domain of $f$ is the real numbers, i.e. $f(x)$ is defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. It also means that the codomain of $f$ is the real numbers, i.e. $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

The problem statement you've been given *does* have a problem, because you've correctly identified that $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is undefined for $x = 0$.

Sometimes, particularly in complex analysis, it is a common shorthand to implicitly "patch over" so-called "removable singularities". That is, if a function $f(x)$ is continuous in a region except for a single point $R \setminus \{x_0\}$, and if setting $f(x_0) = a$ makes it continuous over all of $R$, then we might just implicitly set $f(x_0) = a$. That might be the case here, but doing so when setting a problem like this is a bit sloppy, in my opinion.